# Como manipulara dados dentro de paginas usando tabcontrol

Tags: c#

Boa tare.
Tenho um tabcontrol com duas paginas, acho que podemos dizer assim, na pagina 1 tenho um datagridview que na coluna[0] traz números de notas, e na pagina 2 tenho um txtbox que quero que seja preenchido com o valor que eu selecionar na pagina 1 no datagridview, agora como posso pegar o dado da coluna no datagridview que eta na pagina 1 e levar o valor selecionado para o textbox na pagina 2.
Desde já agradeço.
 Segue meu código do TabControl

```
public partial class frmComissaoPic : Form
    {
        SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DADOSTSTConnectionString);
        public frmComissaoPic()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }
        public SqlConnection conexaoDADOSTST(bool fecharAntes)
        {
            if (fecharAntes)
            {
                conex.Close();
            }

            if (conex.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conex.Open();
            }

            return conex;
        }
        private void frmComissaoPic_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void ListaGridAltera()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand altera = new SqlCommand("usp_SelecaoAjusteComissao", conexaoDADOSTST(true));
                altera.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTA", this.txt_nota.Text);
                altera.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                altera.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(altera);
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);

                dgw_alteracomissao.DataSource = dtLista;

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
                return;
            }
        }
        private void bln_gerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand geracomissao = new SqlCommand("usp_RelatorioComissao", conexaoDADOSTST(true));
                geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VENDEDOR", this.txt_vendedor.Text);
                geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTINICIAL", this.txt_dtinicial.Text);
                geracomissao.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DTFINAL", this.txt_dtfinal.Text);
                geracomissao.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                geracomissao.ExecuteNonQuery();

                SqlDataAdapter dados = new SqlDataAdapter(geracomissao);
                DataTable dtLista = new DataTable();
                dados.Fill(dtLista);

                dgw_comissao.DataSource = dtLista;

                dgw_comissao.Columns["NOTA"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["CLIENTE"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["PRODUTO"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["VALOR PARCELA"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["PARCELA S/ IMPOSTO"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["VENCIMENTO"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["PREÇO VENDA"].ReadOnly = true;
                dgw_comissao.Columns["COMISSÃO VENDEDOR"].Visible = false;

            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Não exstem dados digitados para a consulta, por favor verificar!!!");
                return;
            }
        }
        private void btn_pesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListaGridAltera();
        }
        private void dgw_alteracomissao_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dgw_alteracomissao.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            txt_nfe.Text         = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txt_pedido.Text      = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txt_item.Text        = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                }

        private void btn_gravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("usp_AlteraComissao", conexaoDADOSTST(true));
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTA", this.txt_nfe.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PEDIDO", this.txt_pedido.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ITEM", this.txt_item.Text);
            update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESEJAVEL", float.Parse(this.txt_desejavel.Text));
            update.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            update.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ListaGridAltera();

            txt_nfe.Text         = "";
            txt_pedido.Text      = "";
            txt_item.Text        = "";
            txt_desejavel.Text   = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, com base nas informações que você passou, suponhamos que temos a aba1 com os seguintes itens:

gridview - GridTeste;
2 colunas - coluna0, coluna1;
botão - enviar;

na aba2:
2 textbox - id, nome;

e o código do botão enviar:

```
    private void enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        id.Text = GridTeste.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        nome.Text = GridTeste.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
```

obs: o valor entre [] é referente a coluna, a contagem inicia em 0, então se você tem 2 colunas, seriam elas 0 e 1, se tiver 3 seriam elas 0, 1 e 2, e assim por diante, espero ter ajudado.

o conteúdo do método do botão enviar pode ser usado em um manipulador de eventos diferente, caro queira enviar os valores sem ter que usar o botão.

Comment: Thiago valew pela atenção, então e o seguinte na tab1 eu tenho um datagrid onde preciso pegar o valor da coluna 0 que eu selecionar e este valor ir para um textbox que esta no tab2 sera que consegui explicar melhor.

Comment: para pegar o valor use um manipulador de eventos para capturar o valor do campo e em seguida jogar no textbox: tab2textbox.Text = GridViewName.Rows[GridViewName.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();

Comment: se não conseguir, vou fazer um projeto de exemplo e posto outra resposta com o código.

Comment: Thiago e isso mesmo só que estou colocando este comando dentro do cellclik do datagrid e esta dando erro no selecindex não esta achando

Comment: Vou reformular minha resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado..

Comment: verifique se agora está atendendo o seu pedido de resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado Thiago era isso mesmo que eu precisava...vlw